# Can I set the email address from SP to Idp request?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

When initiating a SAML authentication request (from the Service Provider), is there any way to give the Identity Provider the username/email address to set as a default on login screen? I'd like that username to be added in the IdP's username box.

Using SAML 2.0 with OneLogin
I understand this can be done with the  information within the AuthnRequest, but I cannot see any way of being able to modify that data.

Answer (score 0):

> is there any way to give the Identity Provider the username/email address to set as a default on login screen?

As far as I know, there is no standard way to indicate required attributes as part of a SAML authentication request sent by the SP. If you know this capability exists in the SAML specification, please share a link.

And even so, if hypothetically there was a way to ask for attributes in the authentication requests, that would only *suggest* to the IdP to consider sending and releasing those attributes back to the app; not that the attribute should be used in the login process/forms. That feature, is entirely implementation specific and depends on your choice of the SAML2 identity provider.